# How to create server and deploy webapp into WebSphere Liberty using Cargo?

Tags: java, websphere, websphere-liberty, cargo

I am looking at https://codehaus-cargo.github.io/cargo/WebSphere+Liberty.html and I am rather stuck on how to proceed (in Java) to create a server and install a webapp into it.

The documentation (same page as above, at bottom) mentions properties but it is not clear to me how to map *context name* and *server name* to the listed properties.

Is there a good (or any) example on how to do this?

**UPDATE**

What I mean is how do I do the equivalent of [`server create myserver`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/was_beta_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_admin_script.html) command, followed by [`mvn liberty:deploy`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/was_beta_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rwlp_maven_deploy.html?view=embed)  into the just created `myserver`, followed by `server start myserver`?

Comment: What do you mean by context name and server name? In theory the Liberty cargo container should be a drop-in replacement for any example you have for other application servers that support the standard cargo properties. The container will download, install, create a default server and configure it. If you are looking to use an already existing server that container does not exist. I think that would be an "Existing Local Configuration for installed container" rather than a "Standalone Local Configuration for installed container"

Comment: @Alasdair: I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Liberty standalone cargo container will automatically create a server, so there is no need to create an API. The server name cannot be overridden though and will be called defaultServer.

To deploy an application, or to start and stop the server you can use the normal Java API. The codehause cargo website has some example code for writing a [JUnit test](https://codehaus-cargo.github.io/cargo/Functional+testing.html) using the Java API. I've added the code with the Liberty customization, and I added the code for how to set the context root for the application.

```
    // (1) Optional step to install the container from a URL pointing to its distribution
    Installer installer = new ZipURLInstaller(
        new URL("http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/ibm/websphere/appserver/runtime/wlp-javaee7/8.5.5.9/wlp-javaee7-8.5.5.9.zip"));
    installer.install();

    // (2) Create the Cargo Container instance wrapping our physical container
    LocalConfiguration configuration = (LocalConfiguration) new DefaultConfigurationFactory().createConfiguration(
        "liberty", ContainerType.INSTALLED, ConfigurationType.STANDALONE);
    InstalledLocalContainer container =
        (InstalledLocalContainer) new DefaultContainerFactory().createContainer(
            "liberty", ContainerType.INSTALLED, configuration);
    container.setHome(installer.getHome());

    // (3) Statically deploy some WAR (optional)
    WAR war = new WAR("cargo.war");
    // (4) Set the context root for the application
    war.setContext("/myContext");
    configuration.addDeployable(war);

    // (5) Start the container
    container.start();
```

The properties can be set using the [LocalConfiguration](https://codehaus-cargo.github.io/apidocs/org/codehaus/cargo/container/configuration/LocalConfiguration.html) interface. You would call setPropertyValue using the right key. The property keys are available on constant interfaces like the [GeneralPropertySet](https://codehaus-cargo.github.io/apidocs/org/codehaus/cargo/container/property/GeneralPropertySet.html).

Comment: Too bad we cannot create custom named servers but the defaultServer will do for now. Thank you. Accepted.

Comment: So, I think I have the basics done. I can deploy but the server binds only to loopback address so the server is not accessible outside. I tried with `*` and with `0.0.0.0` in `slc.setProperty(GeneralPropertySet.HOSTNAME, hostname);` but there was no change in `usr\servers\defaultServer\server.xml`.

Comment: If you raise a JIRA and assign it to me I'll take a look.

Comment: The usr/servers/defaultServer/server.xml wont be updated, instead there should be a file called usr/servers/defaultServer/configDropins/overrides/cargo-httpendpoint.xml which overrides the http endpoint to set a host name based on slc.getProperty(GeneralPropertySet.HOSTNAME);